# SVG avoiding whitespace

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svg

I am trying to add SVG images to Wordpress and apply a fixed height, allowing the width to be flexible.[image]

When I define a fixed height via CSS, the width stays 100% but the graphic doesn't fill the space. It results in excess space either side which is a problem.

HTML markup:

```
<img src="example.svg" alt="example" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this extra space so that I can left align the image in keeping with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `preserveAspectRatio = "none"` attribute in the example.svg and set the viewBox attribute accordingly.